# How do I convert a jodatime Duration into a string formatted as hh:mm:ss?

Tags: java, android, time, jodatime

I'm using the jodatime library. I want to display a count-down between now and an end time and display it to the user. I get the duration that I want to display via:

```
Interval time = new Interval(DateTime.now(), end_time);
Duration duration = time.toDuration();
```

Now I want to convert the duration into a string formatted as `hh:mm:ss`. What is the most straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DurationUtils` from [apache.commons.lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DurationFormatUtils.html):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DurationFormatUtils;

DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(duration.getMillis(), "HH:mm:ss")
```

Or you use:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
String formatted = df.format(new Date(duration.getMillis()));
```

Or another very short solution:

```
String formatted = String.format("%1$tI:%1$tM:%1$tS", duration.getMillis());
```

Comment: @Christian While the suggested library "Apache Lang Commons" containing the utility `DurationFormatUtils` works the other two proposals totally fail for two reasons: a) time zone dependent => introduces offset failures if zone is not UTC, b) only applicable for durations smaller than one day